# Grouping an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get an array of objects from an API in the format shown below:

```
[
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":2,
            "participant_name":"Bond James"
         },
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":17,
         "schedule_name":"bug test",
         "job_type":"Registered Nurse",
         "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":10,
         "start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":18,
         "schedule_name":"June Chuk Schedule",
         "job_type":"Coordinator - Operations",
         "schedule_type":"Individual Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":6,
         "start_date":"2022-06-02 09:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-07 15:00:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":2,
            "participant_name":"Bond James"
         },
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":19,
         "schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test",
         "job_type":"People & Culture",
         "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":6,
         "start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00"
      }
   }
]
```

The property `participant_details` contains information about the participants that are attached to the schedule in the property: `schedule_details`

My question is if there is any way possible to group this data by a participant so that the end result has the `schedule_details` grouped into an array of objects by participant, somehing that looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "participant_id":2,
      "participant_name":"Bond James",
      "schedule_details":[
         {
            "schedule_id":17,
            "schedule_name":"bug test",
            "job_type":"Registered Nurse",
            "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts":10,
            "start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00"
         },
         {
            "schedule_id":19,
            "schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test",
            "job_type":"People & Culture",
            "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts":6,
            "start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "participant_id":3,
      "participant_name":"Barkley Charles",
      "schedule_details":[
         {
            "schedule_id":17,
            "schedule_name":"bug test",
            "job_type":"Registered Nurse",
            "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts":10,
            "start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00"
         },
         {
            "schedule_id":18,
            "schedule_name":"June Chuk Schedule",
            "job_type":"Coordinator - Operations",
            "schedule_type":"Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts":6,
            "start_date":"2022-06-02 09:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-06-07 15:00:00"
         },
         {
            "schedule_id":19,
            "schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test",
            "job_type":"People & Culture",
            "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts":6,
            "start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00",
            "end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const input=[{participant_details:[{participant_id:2,participant_name:"Bond James"},{participant_id:3,participant_name:"Barkley Charles"}],schedule_details:{schedule_id:17,schedule_name:"bug test",job_type:"Registered Nurse",schedule_type:"Shared/Grouped Schedule",number_of_shifts:10,start_date:"2022-05-30 23:00:00",end_date:"2022-06-03 06:00:00"}},{participant_details:[{participant_id:3,participant_name:"Barkley Charles"}],schedule_details:{schedule_id:18,schedule_name:"June Chuk Schedule",job_type:"Coordinator - Operations",schedule_type:"Individual Schedule",number_of_shifts:6,start_date:"2022-06-02 09:00:00",end_date:"2022-06-07 15:00:00"}},{participant_details:[{participant_id:2,participant_name:"Bond James"},{participant_id:3,participant_name:"Barkley Charles"}],schedule_details:{schedule_id:19,schedule_name:"Grouped Re-assignment test",job_type:"People & Culture",schedule_type:"Shared/Grouped Schedule",number_of_shifts:6,start_date:"2022-06-04 19:00:00",end_date:"2022-06-10 02:00:00"}}];

console.log(mapResultByParticipant(input));

function mapResultByParticipant(events) {
    const participants = {};

    events.forEach((event) => {
      event.participant_details.forEach((participant) => {
        
        //if we don't have such participant - create him
        if (!participants[participant.participant_id]) {
          participants[participant.participant_id] = {
            ...participant,
            schedule_details: []
          }
        }

        // add event to participant
        participants[participant.participant_id].schedule_details.push(event.schedule_details);
      });
    });

    return Object.values(participants);
}
```

Comment: I will also give you an upvote for it, but not without letting you know `if (!participants[participant.participant_id]) {` creates it already and it's bad practice and can lead to missbehaviours. correct would be `if (!participants.hasOwnProperty(participant.participant_id)) {` to check if it not exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combinaison of 'map' and 'forEach' on your objects array

```js
// objects contains your API result
var objects = [...]
// 1 - Get array of objects where each object has a list of participants
var result = objects.map(obj=>{
  var participants = obj["participant_details"].map(participant=>{
    return {
      "participant_id":participant["participant_id"],
      "participant_name":participant["participant_name"],
      "schedule_details":obj["schedule_details"]
    }
  })
  return {
    "participants": participants
  }
})

// 2 - Compose the final result by pushing every participant in new array
var finalResult = []
result.forEach(obj=>{
   obj["participants"].forEach(p=>{
     finalResult.push(p)
   })
})
console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired result.

We'd call .reduce() once on the input array, then also on the participant_details array for each input.

Once we've grouped the schedule_details, we'll convert to an array again with `Object.values()`

```js
const input = [ { "participant_details":[ { "participant_id":2, "participant_name":"Bond James" }, { "participant_id":3, "participant_name":"Barkley Charles" } ], "schedule_details":{ "schedule_id":17, "schedule_name":"bug test", "job_type":"Registered Nurse", "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule", "number_of_shifts":10, "start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00", "end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00" } }, { "participant_details":[ { "participant_id":3, "participant_name":"Barkley Charles" } ], "schedule_details":{ "schedule_id":18, "schedule_name":"June Chuk Schedule", "job_type":"Coordinator - Operations", "schedule_type":"Individual Schedule", "number_of_shifts":6, "start_date":"2022-06-02 09:00:00", "end_date":"2022-06-07 15:00:00" } }, { "participant_details":[ { "participant_id":2, "participant_name":"Bond James" }, { "participant_id":3, "participant_name":"Barkley Charles" } ], "schedule_details":{ "schedule_id":19, "schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test", "job_type":"People & Culture", "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule", "number_of_shifts":6, "start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00", "end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00" } } ]

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { participant_details, schedule_details }) => { 
    return participant_details.reduce((acc, { participant_id, participant_name }) => { 
        acc[participant_id] = acc[participant_id] || { participant_id, participant_name, schedule_details: [] };
        acc[participant_id].schedule_details.push(schedule_details);
        return acc;
    }, acc);
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":2,
            "participant_name":"Bond James"
         },
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":17,
         "schedule_name":"bug test",
         "job_type":"Registered Nurse",
         "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":10,
         "start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":18,
         "schedule_name":"June Chuk Schedule",
         "job_type":"Coordinator - Operations",
         "schedule_type":"Individual Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":6,
         "start_date":"2022-06-02 09:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-07 15:00:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "participant_details":[
         {
            "participant_id":2,
            "participant_name":"Bond James"
         },
         {
            "participant_id":3,
            "participant_name":"Barkley Charles"
         }
      ],
      "schedule_details":{
         "schedule_id":19,
         "schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test",
         "job_type":"People & Culture",
         "schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule",
         "number_of_shifts":6,
         "start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00",
         "end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00"
      }
   }
];

var result = [];
for (const o of x) {
    if (o.participant_details.length === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    var newObj = {};
    for (const p of o.participant_details) {
        var index = result.findIndex((value) => value.participant_id === p.participant_id && value.participant_name === p.participant_name);
        if (index !== -1) {
            result[index].schedule_details.push(o.schedule_details);
        } else {
            result.push({
                participant_id: p.participant_id,
                participant_name: p.participant_name,
                schedule_details: [
                    o.schedule_details
                ],
            });
        }
    }
}
console.log("%o", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could key the data by participant id in a Map, and give each key an object that has the participant info and an empty schedule array.

Then iterate the data to populate those schedule arrays based on the participant id.

Finally extract the values from the map:

```js
const data = [{"participant_details":[{"participant_id":2,"participant_name":"Bond James"},{"participant_id":3,"participant_name":"Barkley Charles"}],"schedule_details":{"schedule_id":17,"schedule_name":"bug test","job_type":"Registered Nurse","schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule","number_of_shifts":10,"start_date":"2022-05-30 23:00:00","end_date":"2022-06-03 06:00:00"}},{"participant_details":[{"participant_id":3,"participant_name":"Barkley Charles"}],"schedule_details":{"schedule_id":18,"schedule_name":"June Chuk Schedule","job_type":"Coordinator - Operations","schedule_type":"Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts":6,"start_date":"2022-06-02 09:00:00","end_date":"2022-06-07 15:00:00"}},{"participant_details":[{"participant_id":2,"participant_name":"Bond James"},{"participant_id":3,"participant_name":"Barkley Charles"}],"schedule_details":{"schedule_id":19,"schedule_name":"Grouped Re-assignment test","job_type":"People & Culture","schedule_type":"Shared/Grouped Schedule","number_of_shifts":6,"start_date":"2022-06-04 19:00:00","end_date":"2022-06-10 02:00:00"}}];

const map = new Map(data.flatMap((o) => o.participant_details.map(o => 
    [o.participant_id, { ...o, schedule_details: [] }]
)));

for (const o of data) {
    for (const {participant_id} of o.participant_details) {
        map.get(participant_id).schedule_details.push({...o.schedule_details});
    }
}

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```